# Qual o termo atual equivalente a expressões como "o castigo vem a cavalo" ou "a todo vapor"?

Tags: expressões-idiomáticas

Não faz muito sentido dizer que algo é feito "a todo vapor" ou que o castigo vem "a cavalo" nos dias de hoje. Se existe alguma expressão equivalente e atual, talvez faça alguma alusão ao avião, à velocidade da luz, ou à Internet.  Alguma expressão mais coerente com os dias de hoje?

Comment: Vir a cavalo é um simbolismo significando que não veio lentamente como se viesse a pé. Não precisa dizer que " veio de avião a jato".

Comment: Sempre ouvi a expressão como "vem forte" ou "vem bruto".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A expressão "*a todo o vapor*", é muito usada, mas há também a expressão "**a jato**" tendo o mesmo significado, só que menos popular.

São termos arraigados em nossa cultura, mas que se remetem a algo que ficou para trás... "O castigo vem a cavalo" indicava algo rápido, embora que hoje se alguém falar literalmente que vai mandar uma encomenda a cavalo, sabemos que vai demorar...

Acho que na época em que estamos, sabemos que nada é mais rápido que a velocidade da luz, portanto seria muito bom falarmos "à velocidade da luz" para indicar algo extremamente ágil.

Comment: Gostei do "a jato".  Realmente não havia me ocorrido. Quanto a luz, não seria "à velocidade da luz" ?

Comment: @Centaurus Realmente, as expressões "a jato" e "a cavalo" não a crase porque se trata de preposição seguida por substantivo masculino. "À velocidade..." creio que vai crase pois há o substantivo feminino velocidade.

Comment: não há crase, Soares.

Comment: Fiquei com dúvida em relação à crase. A expressão "a jato", é mais fácil por se tratar de substantivo masculino

Comment: as expressões "a jato" e "a cavalo" não **a** crase porque se trata de preposição NÃO **HÁ** CRASE.

Comment: Mas **há crase** em "à velocidade da luz"

Comment: Há uma crise de crases... né, @Centaurus?

Comment: à velocidade da luz nem sempre tem crase. Sé se for precedido de um verbo que leva a proposição **a**.

Answer (score 5):

Algumas equivalentes:

- [a toda a pressa](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/a%20toda%20a%20pressa) ou *à pressa* (mais parecido com *a despachar*);
- [a toda a brida](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/a%20toda%20a%20brida), creio que é uma expressão mais antiga;
- [a toda a velocidade](http://www.fnac.pt/A-Toda-a-Velocidade-Varios/a853175) - mais comum;
- [a correr](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/a%20correr) ou *a acelerar* ou *a dar gás* (mais relacionado com veículos a motor, mas usada [noutros contextos](http://www.meiosepublicidade.pt/2015/12/agua-de-luso-quer-por-toda-a-gente-a-dar-gas-ao-proximo-ano/)).

Answer (score -1):

Muito mais moderno é usar só a sigla como fazem os mais jovens. Pra isso tem o FTL - faster than light

Comment: Mestre, bem-vindo ao site. A sigla é usada só em texto, ou oralmente dizem também *efe-tê-ele*? Convém esclarecer, que a língua não é só escrita...

Comment: Olá MestreLeroy, boas-vindas. Usa-se mesmo FTL em português?